# How to run different computer vision programmes with different media pipe versions on PyCharm?

Tags: python, version-control, computer-vision, mediapipe

I have several media pipe projects. However, some of them require different media pipe versions (older or newer). Is there a way to run all the projects in a single version? if not, how can we shift between the versions without uninstalling it and reinstall the required version? I am using PyCharm IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In case you still have this error, I have solved it by using two different IDEs and installing different media pipe versions on those IDEs separately